# Buy BTC without linking PAN card and aadhar card

Tags: buy-bitcoins, india

How can we buy bitcoins in India without linking our pan card and aadhar card?

Answer (score -1):

Try localbitcoins.com, there is a quick buy option which doesn't require ID